# Is a variable defined in a class "global" i.e. invalid in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nameerror

Can somebody explain to me why, in the following code `ext` is reachable within the `MP3File` class, but not within its `play` method?  Sorry for the short question, that is all I need to know.

```
class MP3File(AudioFile):
    ext = 'mp3'
    print(ext)

    def play(self):
        print(ext) #NameError: global name 'ext' is not defined
```

Comment: Because it's a class attribute, use `self.ext`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ext` is not a global, it is *temporarily* a local when the class is being created. From the [`class` statement documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions):

> The class’s suite is then executed in a new execution frame (see [*Naming and binding*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming)), **using a newly created local namespace** and the original global namespace. (Usually, the suite contains mostly function definitions.) When the class’s suite finishes execution, its execution frame is discarded but its local namespace is saved.

Emphasis mine. The local namespace then forms the class attributes.

By the time your `MP3File.play()` method is being called, that local namespace is long since gone; you cannot just refer to `ext` as if it still exists. It is now a class attribute instead!

You can address that attribute via the `self` reference to an instance. Unless the instance *also* has an `ext` attribute, the class attribute is found and returned instead:

```
def play(self):
    print(self.ext)
```

or you can find it on the class:

```
def play(self):
    print(MP3File.ext)
```

Comment: **"its execution frame is discarded but its local namespace is saved."**

To me this makes it sound like the variable would be deleted altogether. 

Am I right that what is actually happening (strangely, to me) is that it transforms from a 'temporary local variable' to a class attribute with no sort of assignment necessary?

Comment: @Startec: the local names created in the execution frame are used as the attributes on the class object. The assignment has already taken place; it is just a question of using transforming the local namespace into a dictionary; e.g. enumerate the local names as keys, and their values as the associated values in the dictionary.

Comment: @Startec: if you want to know more about that process, read [What is a metaclass in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/100003)